# Calculate number of days in a month

Tags: mysql, sql

On my web page I have 2 text boxes from which I enter the Year and Month. Can you tell me a mysql query which will get the number of days in that month. I want to use that in my code behind and depending on that number of days I need to do other stuff. I searched and found something like this

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY('2012-02-1'));
```

This is my code behind

```
public void search(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cnnString = "Server=localhost;Port=3307;Database=leavesystem;Uid=root;Pwd=ashish";
            MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(cnnString);
            cnx.Open();
            string cmdText = "Select DAY(LAST_DAY(CAST(CONCAT(@'" + year.value +"', '-', @'"+ month.value+"', '-', 1) AS DATE))) ";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnx);

         }
```

This gives me the number of days but I don't have the date. I have 2 text box values year and month. Can you give me the query for that?

Comment: Do you think this is better to do in your `code-behind`? I think you are using `C#`.

Comment: So you want to depend on a database connection to calculate something like this in your code?

Comment: Yes am working in asp.net.Actually I am creating a repeater dynamically for my web page and I dont know the number of columns. So when the user inputs the year and month I want to get the number of days of that month and then generate the columns!!

Comment: _"but I don't have the date. I have 2 text box values year and month"_ - and you can't think of any way of "creating" `2012-02-1` when you already have `2012` and `02`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have the two parameters:

```
SET @y = 2013;
SET @m = 5;
```

`@y` will be the year, and `@m` will be the month.

Since every month has its first day, you can set the day to `1` as constant

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(CAST(CONCAT(@y, '-', @m, '-', 1) AS DATE)));
```

By the way, I'm using session variables, I think you will be using `INPUT` parameters, I guess it will be the same.

**EDIT 1**

If the month passed in the query is `MONTHNAME`, you can change it in the `code-behind` already. But if you insist, here is the query to get the `MONTHNUMBER`:

```
SET @m = MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('June', '%M'));
```

Here is the final query:

```
SET @y = 2013;
SET @m = 'June';

SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(CAST(CONCAT(@y, '-', MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(@m, '%M')), '-', 1) AS DATE)));
```

Comment: Thanks KaeL. Your code works fine. Now am working on generating the repeater. Hope it works. Cheers :)

Comment: I see. I'd be happy if you accept my answer. Just click the checkmark on the top left side of my answer :)

Comment: Did that bro. Hey man are you familiar with repeater. I have tried but am not getting it right. If you can then please help me with that. Here is my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314479/generate-repeater-depending-on-number-dynamically-generated

Comment: I'll check that post of yours :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you give by defaults the `01` first of every month in the query, don't know your programming language but just to give an idea

```
var date_vaiable=year_variable+"-"month_variable+"-01"; //+ sign is for concat concept

SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(date_vaiable));
```